# How to write a script to generate script SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I want to write a script for generate insert into script.

I have a `NewJob` table. It has some rows. I want to generate `insert into` statements using script like this:

```
INSERT [Computer A].[newjob] ([Id], [Newjob], [jobNo]) VALUES (1, N'A', 4)
INSERT [Computer A].[newjob] ([Id], [Newjob], [jobNo]) VALUES (2, N'b', 8)
INSERT [Computer A].[newjob] ([Id], [Newjob], [jobNo]) VALUES (3, N'c', 12)
```

Can I do this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this using a select statement and some basic string manipulation. The Select statement will produce an insert statement for each row returned.

```
SELECT 'INSERT INTO [Computer A].[newjob] ([Id]) VALUES (' + Id + ')'
FROM [Computer A].[newjob]
```

I have only included one parameter here, but you can fill in the rest by adding the columns you want to add

Comment: Are you sure you want 2 `insert`s?

Comment: I think the from is missing a `[` too

Answer (score 1):

I think the best way is to make use Script option from SSMS

SSMS-->Right click on database-->Tasks-->Generate scripts-->Choose the table-->Advanced

In the option **Types of data to script**, choose **Data only**